# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable > ParseResource

Tags: android

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable

> Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file /Users/mac/Documents/KotlinMulti/AbKeyDemo/app/build/intermediates/incremental/debug/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not add resource (com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@59403c39) to table.,Can not add resource (com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5d7fa3c9) to table.,Can not add resource (com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@187d3602) to table.,Can not add resource (com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@71d6e7b4) to table.). Check logs for more details.

Facing the issue regarding keyboard app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implementation 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'

Remove this library and upgrade the code